# C++ IDE with repl?

Tags: c++, ide, read-eval-print-loop

I'm looking for a good C++ IDE with a REPL. The one in visual studio isn't... well lets say most of the time if I copy/paste a line in source the REPL rejects it even if its the line I put a breakpoint or step over.

Are there any good IDEs or REPLs for C++?

Comment: http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint

Comment: http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling

Comment: http://www.artificialworlds.net/wiki/IGCC/IGCC

Answer (score 20):

### Cling

#### What is Cling?

Cling is an interactive C++ interpreter, built on the top of LLVM and Clang libraries. Its advantages over the standard interpreters are that it has command line prompt and uses just-in-time (JIT) compiler for compilation. Many of the developers (e.g. Mono in their project called CSharpRepl) of such kind of software applications name them interactive compilers.

One of Cling's main goals is to provide contemporary, high-performance alternative of the current C++ interpreter in the ROOT project - CINT. The backward-compatibility with CINT is major priority during the development.

http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling

Comment: This seems good. It looks like its only available for linux. I'm not sure what to expect. Do I use a GDB compatible IDE (I dont know any) and use breakpoints/repl as expected when pointing to the cling compiler (rather than g++)?

Answer (score 10):

### CINT

#### What is CINT?

CINT is an interpreter for C and C++ code. It is useful e.g. for situations where rapid development is more important than execution time. Using an interpreter the compile and link cycle is dramatically reduced facilitating rapid development. CINT makes C/C++ programming enjoyable even for part-time programmers.

CINT is written in C++ itself, with slightly less than 400,000 lines of code. It is used in production by several companies in the banking, integrated devices, and even gaming environment, and of course by ROOT, making it the default interpreter for a large number of high energy physicists all over the world.

http://www.hanno.jp/gotom/Cint.html

Answer (score 3):

CLing should be independant of Clang and abble to compile on any platform, recent works of CERN tend to separate Cling from Clang and it's good trends.

What I don't under is mostly the existence of Clipp in C++ allowing to parse javascript embedded in my C++ code and can't find a version of Clipp for just C++ / Boost / Eigen / Quantlib.

Another thing I don't understand is why TinyCC with a 200ko size is abble to parse windows.h without a problem and LLVM team complaining about Clang on windows.H detonate on tarmac.

All in all, with fusion, spirit, wave and the so many people wishing for a C++ REPL, why after 2 decade there is not even small version of it.

Here is my solutions

Forget about REPL C++ and stick to REPL C, use tinyCC and expose only the functionnal action of method by using pointer function A.function(toto t) -> function(A *, toto t). To make it works with object method you can also use declaration as struct __declspec(novtable) A { };

This will allow binary align compatibility between tinyCC struct understanding and your true object. True you will have to split the tuple of data and the tuple of method, but after all, that should have always be the case in first place. Object design should have split data and method into a dual model rather than a mixed model good for bug. In many case, the compiler will split the object into dual model anyway. This will provide extrem fast prototyping even for scientist and user of Cling/Cint.

Second solution, rather than REPL statement, use the dynamic load/unload pair, you setup a chain of compilation ( incremental build or not ) and auto relink compiled library when the source change. It isn't slow at all. This give the advantage to do it on any supported dynamic library OS and it's very EASY to do.

Third solution, the most easiest way, boot a linux based vm ( install llvm tool chain), and use Cling on the vm. That won't work in a firm full windowOSed but it seems LLVM are windows OS haters.